# Color not appearing when writing from HTML using Fpdf

Tags: python, streamlit, pyfpdf

So I'm creating a `streamlit` web app where people provide a paragraph and I split it up into sentences and allow them to download it as a PDF after applying color-blind friendly color coding. To do this, I create HTML and add the color coding as a style attribute. I then try and download it using `fpdf2`. However, when I open the downloaded PDF, there is no color.

```
class PDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass

def create_html(text, hex_codes):
    result = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    hex1 = hex_codes[0]
    hex2  = hex_codes[1]
    flag = True
    res = []
    for sentence in result:
        if flag:
            hex = hex1
        else:
            hex = hex2
        flag = not flag
        res.append(f"<p style ='color:{hex}'>{sentence}</p>")
    return ''.join(res)

def create_pdf(html):
    pdf = PDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.write_html(html)
    return BytesIO(pdf.output())
```

Is there any reason this happens?

Comment: Does `create_html()` return the right colors in its HTML?

Comment: Yup. When I display the html created in the we page, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [docs](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/HTML.html), it looks like coloring works with the `<font>` tag:

```
res.append(f"<p><font color='{hex}'>{sentence}</font></p>")
```